# Prove Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm working this function:

$f(t,x)=\frac{4t^3x}{t^4+x^2}$ for $(t,x)\neq(0,0);$

$f(t,x)=0$ for $(t,x)=(0,0)$

As I proved continuity using the line $x=t^2$, I need to study if it's globally Lipschitz. I tried to derivate on $x$, and I got:

$\frac{df(t,x)}{dx}=\frac{4t^3(t^4+x^2)-8t^3x^2}{(t^4+x^2)^2}=\frac{4t^3(t^4-x^2)}{(t^4+x^2)^2}$

So if $(t,x)\to (0^+,0^+), \frac{df(t,x)}{dx}\to +\infty$. Would it be a proof to negate the global Lipschitz condition? And this would be enough to study the local Lipschitz condition?

Thank you very much

Update: Fixed $\frac{df(t,x)}{dx}$ to avoid mistakes

Comment: Do you mean a Lipschitz condition with respect to $x$?

Comment: Didn't You miss a factor $2$ when differentiating?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the $2$ now you told me.

Comment: If this appeared in the context of differential equations, what You typically need to prove existence and uniqueness of solutions is a Lipschitz-condition $|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|\leq L|x_1-x_2|$, so boundedness of the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is sufficient

Comment: I have to correct myself, it isn't sufficient. The constant $L$ mustn't depend on $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the quotient rule You should get
$$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=\frac{4t^3(t^4+x^2)-4t^3 2x}{(t^4+x^2)^2}=\frac{4t^7-4t^3x^2}{(t^4+x^2)^2}$$
and thus 
$$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=0.$$
Furthermore for each $t\neq 0$ the denominator of the derivative $\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}$ is bounded from below, thus the derivative is bounded and so the function $f_t:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto f(t,x)$ is Lipschitz-continuous ( by a mean-value theorem-argument) with a Lipschitzconstant $L_t$. (For $t=0$ this map $f_0$ is the zero map.) But one can see that 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}L_t=\infty$$ and thus one can't establish a global Lipschitz-condition of the form
$$|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|\leq L|x_1-x_2|$$
$\textbf{ for all }$ $t,x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. If one considers restrictions
$f_{|I\times\mathbb{R}}$ where $I$ is an interval that does not contain $0$ this is possible and the corresponding boundary value problem has a unique solution by Picard- Lindelöff's theorem. (The counterexample $x_1(t)=t^2,x_2(t)=-t^2$ doesn't work then because if $I=[a,b]$ then $x_1(a)\neq x_2(a)$ in this case (since $a\neq 0$).

Comment: My question is: if $f(t,x)$ is globally Lipschitz-continuous, why can we find two different solutions on $x(t)=t^2$ and $x(t)=-t^2$ when, by Lipschitz Theorem, if $f(t,x)$ is globally Lipschitz-continuous, then the solution should be unique?

Comment: Good point! Didn't notice that at a first glance. I edited my answer!

Comment: In that case, we are saying that our function is locally Lipschitz-continuous but not globally, since we can't bound that constant if $t\to 0$

Comment: Exactly! The condition of global Lipschitz-continuity has to be read quite carefully!